# How to compare the value of variable from CSV file using beanshell scripting?

Tags: json, csv, jmeter

I am using JSON extractor to extract the value from the response and then I need to search the CSV and get the value from the CSV for that specific value.

Like I am getting the value from JSON extractor is XYZ and then I need to search the CSV where the value is stored as

```
**Col1**   **Col2**
ABC    123
DEF    456
XYZ    890
```

Can anyone guide me to the right direction about how to fetch the value from CSV using bean shell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read lines, Use split by comma to get columns values
Find column value XYZ and assign column 2 value to jmeter variable:

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(flatFile));
  scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");
  while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.next();
    String cells[] = line.split(",");  

       if (cells[0].equals("XYZ")) {
         vars.put("myVal2",  cells[1]);
        }
       }
```

Comment: Minor modification was required which I did below. Thanks for the help.


  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(flatFile));
  scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");
  while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.next();
    String[] cells = line.split(",");  

       if (cells[0].equals("XYZ")) {
         vars.put("myVal2",  cells[1]);
        }
       }

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Beanshell for scripting, go for JSR223 Elements and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language instead. Beanshell has known performance problems and it will become your test's bottleneck assuming large number of users.

The relevant Groovy code would be something like:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').filterLine(writer) { line ->
    line.contains(vars.get('VARIABLE_FROM_JSON_EXTRACTOR_REFERENCE_NAME'))
}

def value = writer.toString().split(",")[1].replace(System.getProperty('line.separator'), '')

vars.put('value', value)
```

You will be able to access the value from CSV file as `${value}` where required.

References:

- `vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class, it provides read/write access to JMeter Variables
- other code should be self-explanatory
- [JMeter Best Practices: JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)